# Hello World Console Application running three threads?

Tags: .net, clr, console-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why 3 threads for a basic single threaded c# console app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762316/why-3-threads-for-a-basic-single-threaded-c-console-app)

Steps:

1. Created a Console Application (c#) in .net.
2. Wrote the below 3-4 lines of code in Program.cs

   class Program
   {

   ```
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           HelloWorkd();
           Console.Read();
       }
       static void HelloWorkd()
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
       }
   ```

   }
3. Build the project, in debug mode.
4. Browsed to the .exe that is generated and start it.
5. Started Task Manager, and had a look the process in which this exe is running. And it shows that 3 thread are running in this application!!!

Question: How come a simple program is showing three threads? I can accept 2 threads here, one for GC and other for my console, what is the third thread doing?

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why 3 threads for a basic single threaded c# console app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762316/why-3-threads-for-a-basic-single-threaded-c-console-app)

Comment: Got the answer in the duplicate thread. Thanks.