# default number of threads created for a simple console application

Tags: c#

I have a specific query about threads created for console application.
I created a simple c# console application which just prints Hello World. In the taskmanager for this application's process the number of threads shown are 10.
I can think of 2 threads : one for writing to console and one for Garbage Collection.
 what about the other 8 threads ? 
Also is the number of threads created depends on the machine configuration or .net framework version ?

Comment: I get ~10 when running in Visual Studio but only ~4 when running the .exe directly, in case that adds any insight.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762316/why-3-threads-for-a-basic-single-threaded-c-sharp-console-app

Comment: Don't forget the debugger, the JIT compiler, etc. etc.

Comment: This is a duplicate but cant find the original right now. Try having a look for similar question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @spender but can we always pinpoint the exact number of threads  taking into account no. of cores, .net framework version, 32bit/64bit machine or any other configuration parameters ?